# Counting this in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection called `orders` in the `main` database. To count all the orders, I type

```
use main
db.orders.count()
```

All the orders documents have the `customer_email_address`. Each customers can have many orders.

How can I count all unique email addresses?

Also, how can I count all unique email addresses that are NOT in a list of a few particular email addresses like `my_own_address@gmail.com` and `my_coworkers_address@gmail.com` (Me and my coworkers have placed some test orders and we'd like to ignore those.)

Comment: use .group() or execute mapreduce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simple distinct with query

```
db.orders.distinct(
    'customer_email_address',
    {customer_email_address:
        {$nin: ["my_own_address@gmail.com", "my_coworkers_address@gmail.com"]}
    }
).length
```

With aggregation framework:

```
pipeline = [
    {
        "$match" : {
            "customer_email_address" : {
                "$nin" : [
                    "my_own_address@gmail.com",
                    "my_coworkers_address@gmail.com"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group" : {
            "_id" : "$customer_email_address",
            "count" : {
                "$sum" : 1
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group" : {
            "_id" : null,
            "count" : {
                "$sum" : 1
            }
        }
    }
]
db.orders.aggregate(pipeline).result[0].count
```